# Contact Form with Text Area filling remaining content

Tags: css

I am trying to create a contact form similar to the design bellow, but can't seem to get the correct result. I thought I could do this with flex-box, but I am having trouble getting the Text Area to Display correctly. If there is a better way to do this with keeping the HTML structure the same, I am open to suggestions.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BexbXj)

[image]

```
<form class="flex-container">
  <ul>
  <li>
    <input type="text" placeholder="left">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" placeholder="left">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" placeholder="left">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" placeholder="right">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" placeholder="left">
  </li>
  <li class="text-area">
    <textarea placeholder="right"></textarea>
  </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: `<li>` cannot be a direct descendant of any other element except for `<ol>` or `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a more quick solution but you can do that with bootstrap :

```
<form class="container">
<div class="col-5 row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class = "row">   
            <input type="text" placeholder="left">
        </div> 
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="left">
        </div>   
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="left">
        </div>   
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="left">    
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 ml-3">
        <div class = "row">       
            <input type="text" placeholder="left">
        </div> 
         <div class = "row mt-3 heightCSS">
            <textarea placeholder="right"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.heightCSS{
height: 8em;
width: 14em;
```

}

Comment: I tried throwing that into codepen with bootstrap 4, but it did not work. It did however give me an idea how to solve my problem, although I had to adjust the HTML slightly. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you forgot jquery in your index.html?
paste this inside body tag
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>